# Use of shared database in Windows 8 App

Tags: sqlite, windows-8, share

I am developing a set of apps for Windows 8 which require local data storage and I'm experiencing a trouble in accessing the data from these apps. As far as I know, each app has its own location to store its data. Is it principally possible to access one file in Windows.Storage from different apps? I am using SQLite as a database server and it is necessary to have one common database to share data between the apps.

Answer (score 0):

No, the applications are sandboxed so they cannot access each other's local data storage.  If you're willing to have your application initialization process ask the user where to put/find the SQLite database, then the applications could share that same file at a location on the file system that the user has selected via the File Picker.

That means, of course, that the user has to remember where the file is whenever he first launches the "second" app, since he'll need to browse to the same location where he "first" app deposited it.

If you leverage [AccessCache.StorageItemAccessList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.accesscache.storageitemaccesslist.aspx), though, you can save that file location in your app's local storage, so the next time the user runs either app he doesn't have to go through the File Picker to grant permission again.

Comment: I have the exact same issue. I'm also relying on an SQLite file that is specific to my first app. I would like to initialize my second app with that data. What I don't want to do is force the user to perform a user action that he/she should not even care about. There must be a better solution for this. Has anyone found the solution for this problem that does not expose implementation details to the user?